# Additional header - Azure Data Factory

Tags: json, api, format, azure-data-factory, content-type

Im trying to convert my file from "binary" (application/octet-stream) to a JSON. Im trying to write: Content-Type: application/json into additinoal header but im still getting the same file.

I need to convert this file to contuine working with it, hopefully somone can help me witht this problem!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, REST connector ignores any "Accept" header specified in additionalHeaders.

> REST connector ignores any "Accept" header specified in
> additionalHeaders. As REST connector only support response in JSON, it
> will auto generate a header of Accept: application/json.

[image]

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#copy-activity-properties